# Identifying a Diode: "1042 MZ"

Tags: diodes, identification

I am organizing a bunch of components given to me; some of them not put in a labeled bag.

This SMB diode has the marking "1042 MZ" on it and I cannot find any references to this. And I have checked a [SMD Code book](https://www.sphere.bc.ca/download/smd-codebook.pdf) without finding anything.

I am running out of good ideas :)

[image: Unknown diode]

**Edit:**
Applying 1V in forward direction made it hot and conduct 2A.
Slowly increasing the reverse bias voltage with an LED in series confirmed that it is a unidirectional TVS diode starting to conduct at about 70 volts.

Comment: Do you have enough to be able to do some destructive tests to figure out what you have?

Comment: Yes, I got a hundred pieces (therefore a shame just to discard them). So I could easily let one release its magic smoke.

Comment: It blocks in reverse direction up to the 60V my power supply can deliver. Applying 1 volt in the forward direction it conducts 2A and of course gets smoking HOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a generic version of the [SMBJ51A](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf), a 51V SMB unidirectional TVS.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment of my original question. Can it be a TVS when it conducts at about 800mV (2A) when applying a postive voltage to the anode. And it blocks up to 60V when reverse biased?

Comment: It is better to edit changes into your question at the bottom rather than to use comments. Yes, it's possible. If you read the datasheet I linked, the forward voltage is 800mV at 2A for a single die unit (the indicated construction), and it may not conduct more than 1mA at 62.7V. You would need more voltage than 60V to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me; I will add it to the original post. I will try with a little more voltage and a proper multimeter.